# generate random username automatically in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there any way to generate the username automatically. and I also need username while signing in so it must be unique-

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null= False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)
```

below is the code for user create serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
username = serializers.CharField(label="username field",
                                     required=True, allow_null=False,
                                     allow_blank=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'profile')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, 'first_name': {'required': True},
                    'last_name': {'required': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    try:
        if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=User(**validated_data).username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("username already exists")
    except Exception as e:
            error = {'message': ",".join(e.args) if len(e.args) > 0 else 'Unknown Error'}
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)
    user = User(**validated_data)
    print(user.username)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

what changes should i make to generate username automatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this method: `from allauth.utils import generate_unique_username`

Then you can generate unique usernames like this:

```
# Create user object
first_name = 'My firstname'
last_name = 'My lastname'
email = 'myemail@gmail.com'

user = User()
user.first_name = first_name
user.last_name = last_name
user.email = email
user.username = generate_unique_username([f'{first_name} {last_name}', email, 'user'])
user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should raise `ValidationError` only from `validate` functions.
2. Use managers to create objects. `User` model has built-in `create_user` method.
3. To generate username you could use a library such as [`coolname`](https://github.com/alexanderlukanin13/coolname).
4. Create two serializers. One for creating user and another one for reading.
5. If you want to allow users to specify their own username, add a validator on the field.
6. Move profile creation to `create_user` method.

```
from coolname import generate_slug

class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=3, 
        max_length=50, 
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())], 
        allow_null=True, 
        default=None
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def validate_username(self, val):
        return val or generate_slug()
    
    def perform_create(self, validated_data):
        # use User manager
        ...
```